# How can I add numbers before my output here?

Tags: c++, string, variables, numbers, output

I'm working on a C++ program for my class and I'm unsure about a specification.  I want to add numbers before the output of string orderCode but am unsure how to do this.  For example, output for the input "BF12" would be "12 Black Forest cakes."  I am trying to include the number and amount of cakes into one single string variable. Could anyone offer me some pointers?  Anything would be very much appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

string orderCode;
string repeat = "y";
while ("y" == repeat) {

cout << "\nWelcome to the Great Cake company!\n";
cout << "\nEnter the cake order code: ";
cin >> orderCode;

int quantity = orderCode.length() - 1;


if (orderCode == "BF2")
{ (cout << orderCode.substr(quantity) << " Black Forest cakes");
}

if (orderCode == "CC")
  { (cout << "Carrot cakes");
}

  if (orderCode == "CM")
     { (cout << "Chocolate Mint cakes");
}

  if (orderCode == "DF")
     { (cout << "Devil's Food cakes");
}

  if (orderCode == "GC")
     { (cout << "German Chocolate cakes");
}

  if (orderCode == "PC")
     { (cout << "Pumpkin Cheesecakes");
}

  if (orderCode == "RC")
     { (cout << "Rum cakes");
}

  if (orderCode == "T")
     { (cout << "Tiramisu cakes");
}

cout << "\nOrder more? (y/n) ";
cin >> repeat;
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: From what I can tell, you're not asking how to "add numbers". You're asking how to parse an input based on some predefined format. That's a completely different kettle of fish.

Comment: Yes, that's more what I was going for.  I wasn't sure how to phrase it exactly.  Any pointers? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: do the numbers come from anyplace in particular? based on the question I'd guess the order code...

Comment: Yes, they come from the order code. Ex: if the input for value orderCode was "DF12" it would output "12 Devil's Food cakes," or "GC8" would output "8 German Chocolate cakes."

Comment: @joegame First, you write a *very small* program so you can practice how to input two separate items into two separate variables.  You don't need all of the code you posted [to do this](http://ideone.com/ISzyLq).  Then when you know how to do this, **then** you add that to your larger program.  Trying to write the whole program in one shot without knowing how to do the simple things is not the way to write a program.

Comment: Forgot to add I am trying to include the number and cake type into one single string variable.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You can use the function `strcspn()` to find the first numeric character in the string.

Comment: does that return the index? he'll probably want to copy everything before the index of that character...

Comment: @ScegfOd Exactly. `strcspn(orderCode.c_str(), "0123456789")` returns the index of the first number. Everything before that is the product code, everything after is the quantity.

Answer (score 1):

You want to parse the user input, assuming the digit will always be after the letters and assuming the digit is a decimal (thus not counting ABCDEF as part of the digit).

```
string orderCode = "BF12";
size_t last_index = orderCode.find_last_not_of("0123456789");
string result = orderCode.substr(last_index + 1);
result += " Black Forest cakes";
cout << result << endl;
```

Meanwhile for your switch case you still need to erase the digit part of the input.

```
orderCode.erase(last_index+1);
```

You can then compare to `orderCode`

Answer (score 0):

You need to omit BF and exctract the number. Since BF has length of 2, you need to print the rest:

```
cout << orderCode.substr(2, quantity) << " Black Forest cakes"
```

Meanwhile, your switch case does not make any sense.